# Angular matMenuTriggerRestoreFocus doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-material2

Do I misunderstand something?

**Template:**

```html
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" [matMenuTriggerRestoreFocus]="false">Menu</button>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
</mat-menu>
```

**Error:**

```
Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'matMenuTriggerRestoreFocus' since it isn't a known property of 'button'.
```

**Update: my problem was solved by updating to angular material 8.0.2**

Answer (score 0):

you need to import **`MatMenuModule`** in your current module which your component resides in.

```
 imports: [
  MatMenuModule
]
```

import it from

```
 import { MatMenuModule} from '@angular/material/menu';
```

Comment: All angular material modules and components are imported and work perfectly. The problem is that I can't use matMenuTriggerRestoreFocus with matMenuTriggerFor .

Answer (score 0):

There is no

> *matMenuTriggerRestoreFocus*

in the example here

> https://material.angular.io/components/menu/examples
>   It cant read.

Here is the code.

```
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu</button>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
</mat-menu>
```

Correct me if I'm wrong please :)